# Script affects all divs, how can I get it to affect just one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node-webkit, nwjs

I am using this function in NW.JS to get a file locations of images. I use that file location in the callback to modify a div background using .css() in jquery. My problem is that the script seems to remember the last div that it modified. When I try to use this to change the background of another div after previously having used it to change the background on a different div BOTH divs change their backgrounds. I guess I need to be able to get this script to know what button clicked it and to forget anything that another button asked it to do. As you can tell I am new to javascript. How can I do that?

```
function chooseFile(name, handleFile) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    for(var f of this.files){
        console.log(f.name);
        console.log(f.path);
        handleFile(f.name, f.path);
    }
   }, false);
   chooser.click();  
}
chooseFile('#fileDialog', function(name, path){ ... /* do something with the file(s) */ });
```

Comment: Are you have multiple elements which have same  `fileDialog`?

Comment: Oh I see!! Of course!! Thank you very much for your fast response. I completely understand now. Very obvious but I missed it entirely. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases, it’ll make sense to write your script so that it can react to new files:

```
const chooser = document.getElementById('fileDialog');

// Treat chooser as a stream of new files that can be added at any time
chooser.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    for (const f of this.files) {
        console.log(f.name);
        console.log(f.path);
        handleFile(f.name, f.path);
    }
}, false);

// Then, when you want to prompt for a new file at any point in the future…
function promptForFiles() {
    chooser.click();
}
```

When that’s not possible, you can instead have it hold a maximum of one handler at a time by assigning to the old but reliable `onchange` property:

```
function chooseFile(name, handleFile) {
    const chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.onchange = function () {
        for (const f of this.files) {
            console.log(f.name);
            console.log(f.path);
            handleFile(f.name, f.path);
        }
    };
    chooser.click();  
}
```

Comment: Using “onchange” works perfectly in my situation. Thank you.

Comment: I am suddenly getting... "TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null" when I try to use this script now. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Marley: `#fileDialog` is missing from the page at that time?

Comment: Yeah man! Thanks! It’s always the simplest things that mess my head up. Completely overlooked the fact I had removed that. Just assumed it was still in code.